Why is the layout not working properly for Regular Modifers in this function?
for some reason the layout does not Work properly for normal Modifiers.

all the NODES modifiers and there properties stack correctly in the layout when they are expanded or collapsed no matter what order

the regular modifiers stack in the layout correctly and work as expected except when expanded and above another modifier which results in every modifier below being hidden until collapse again .


the goal is to have all modifiers visible in the stack no matter what is expanded or collapsed
keep in mind that everything works as expected with The NODES modifiers they stack properly when above and expanded .
def draw_modifier_properties(self, context, layout, obj):
        # Loop through all modifiers
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            # Create a box for each modifier (header + content)
            box = layout.box()

        # Create a row for the modifier's header (name, expand toggle, remove button)
            row = box.row(align=True)
            row.prop(modifier, "show_expanded", icon="TRIA_DOWN" if modifier.show_expanded else "TRIA_RIGHT", emboss=False, text=modifier.name)
            row.operator("magic_menu.remove_modifier", text="", icon='X').modifier_name = modifier.name

            # If the modifier is expanded, display its properties within the same box
            if modifier.show_expanded:
                # Create a column inside the box to contain the expanded properties
                col = box.column()

                # Special handling for NODES type modifiers
                if modifier.type == "NODES":
                    socket_names = {
                        f"{item.identifier}_attribute_name": item.name
                        for item in modifier.node_group.interface.items_tree if item.in_out == "INPUT"
                    }
                    for prop in modifier.bl_rna.properties:
                        if not prop.is_readonly and prop.identifier not in {
                            'name', 'type', 'show_viewport', 'show_render', 'show_in_editmode',
                            'show_on_cage', 'show_expanded', 'use_apply_on_spline', 'show_expanded_in_editmode',
                            'open_bake_data_blocks_panel', 'open_manage_panel', 'use_pin_to_last', 'bake_directory',
                            'show_group_selector', 'is_active', 'open_output_attributes_panel', 'open_named_attributes_panel',
                            'open_bake_panel', 'node_group'
                        }:
                            col.prop(modifier, prop.identifier, text=prop.name)

                    for socket in modifier.node_group.interface.items_tree:
                        if isinstance(socket, bpy.types.NodeTreeInterfaceSocketCollection):
                            if hasattr(modifier, socket.identifier):
                                if not modifier.bl_rna.properties[socket.identifier].is_readonly:
                                    col.prop(modifier, f'["{socket.identifier}"]', text=socket.name)
                        elif isinstance(socket, bpy.types.NodeTreeInterfaceSocketMaterial):
                            if hasattr(modifier, socket.identifier):
                                if not modifier.bl_rna.properties[socket.identifier].is_readonly:
                                    col.prop(modifier, f'["{socket.identifier}"]', text=socket.name)

                    for key in modifier.keys():
                        if not ('_attribute_name' in key or 'use_attribute' in key):
                            attr_name_key = f"{key}_attribute_name"
                            if attr_name_key in socket_names:
                                col.prop(modifier, f'["{key}"]', text=socket_names[attr_name_key])

                # Handling for regular (non-NODES) modifiers
                else:
                    # Loop through the properties of the regular modifier
                    for prop in modifier.bl_rna.properties:
                        if not prop.is_readonly and prop.identifier not in {
                            'name', 'type', 'show_viewport', 'show_render', 'show_in_editmode',
                            'show_on_cage', 'show_expanded', 'use_apply_on_spline', 'show_expanded_in_editmode',
                            'open_bake_data_blocks_panel', 'open_manage_panel', 'use_pin_to_last', 'bake_directory',
                            'show_group_selector', 'is_active', 'open_output_attributes_panel', 'open_named_attributes_panel',
                            'open_bake_panel', 'node_group'
                        }:
                            col.prop(modifier, prop.identifier, text=prop.name)

                    # Display dynamic key-value pairs if they exist
                    for key in modifier.keys():
                        if hasattr(modifier, key):
                            col.prop(modifier, f'["{key}"]', text=key)
                            attr = getattr(modifier, key)
                            if hasattr(attr, "name"):
                                col.label(text=f"{key}: {attr.name}")
            
            # Ensure all modifier boxes remain visible, whether expanded or not
            box.use_property_decorate = False  # Disable prope

i have been banging my head for ages trying to get the regular modifiers to stack propely and not obfuscate other modifiers when above and expanded.
